# converting rgb to yuv etc. using C# with Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, rgb, yuv

I have to make a question for school that have to do with C# in Microsoft Visual Studio.

This is what I suppose to do with a image:

•Implement RGB to YUV conversion

• Implement YUV to RGB conversion.

• Convert a RGB image to YUV and then the converted image in YUV to
RGB and display the initial image and the result (they should look like
the same). Display both images in a window.

• Implement the Black and White filter both in RGB and YUV. Display the
original image and the black and white image in a window.

I am so far that I can display two images side by side, but I just can't convert them or implement it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using ImageUtilities;


namespace Template
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Color[,] image1 = ImageViewer.LoadImage(@"Content\terminator_marine.jpg");
            Color[,] image2 = ImageViewer.LoadImage(@"Content\forest.jpg");
            ImageViewer.DrawImagePair(image1, image2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close since there is unfortunately no attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: There is a attempt to solve the problem. I quote "I am so far that I can display two images side by side, but I just can't convert them or implement it."

Comment: What Sami is referring to is the lack of effort in trying to do absolutely anything other than just simply displaying two images.

Comment: I understand but keep in mind that I'm new in C# and to display the two images was hard enough. I just want a push in the right direction

Comment: Since image manipulation is not something you'd normally be tasked with in your average introductory programming course I'm assuming you're familiar with programming, albeit a different language? I'd say you probably want to look at the bytes of your image which can be achieved by using the MemoryStream class.